# kernel calls cause data abort

Tags: c, exception, linux-kernel

I am getting a data_abort exception in embedded Linux extremely rarely (kern=2.6.10) ARM processor

My trace is showing that I get
do_DataAbort from __dabt_svc which is the handler of data abort
do_page_fault from do_DataAbort
do_page_fault from somewhere in exit.c
hit BUG_ON

BUG_ON(p == reaper || reaper->state >= EXIT_ZOMBIE || reaper->exit_state >= EXIT_ZOMBIE);

in function static inline void choose_new_parent - in file exit.c
this function obviously checking the parent of task (struct task_struct) in linux/kernel/sched.h

Anyone here can confirm that I am starting or ending a task in the kernel when I call any of these:

```
iowrite8 ioread8
__kfifo_get / reset / put / len
wake_up
wait_event_interruptible_timeout
free_irq / disable_irq / request_irq
release / request _mem_region
copy_to / from _user
s3c2410_gpio_cfgpin_outp / inp / alt / pullup
_raw_modifyl / writel / readl
local_irq_restore / save
unregister_chrdev_region
kmalloc
clk_get_rate
```

Any of those might be related to creating a new task to the kernel?

I tried tracing back the header files but it is a real maze!
Thanks in advance